# Bad value for type long in postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am having a java application with Pojo being

```
 public class ArtifactBlobs{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String guid;
    private String workspaceId;
    private Blob artifactBlobValue;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Long createdBy;
    private Date updatedAt;
    private Long updatedBy;
    private Set waasArtifactsBlobsMetas = new HashSet(0);

    public ArtifactsBlobs() {
    }

    public ArtifactsBlobs(String guid, Date createdAt, Date updatedAt) {
        this.guid = guid;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public ArtifactsBlobs(String guid, String workspaceId,
            Blob artifactBlobValue, Date createdAt, Long createdBy,
            Date updatedAt, Long updatedBy) {
        this.guid = guid;
        this.workspaceId = workspaceId;
        this.artifactBlobValue = artifactBlobValue;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return this.guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public String getWorkspaceId() {
        return this.workspaceId;
    }

    public void setWorkspaceId(String workspaceId) {
        this.workspaceId = workspaceId;
    }

    public Blob getArtifactBlobValue() {
        return this.artifactBlobValue;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("CPD-START")
    public void setArtifactBlobValue(Blob artifactBlobValue) {
        this.artifactBlobValue = artifactBlobValue;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return this.createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Long getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return this.updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Long getUpdatedBy() {
        return this.updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(Long updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Set getWaasArtifactsBlobsMetas() {
        return this.waasArtifactsBlobsMetas;
    }

    public void setWaasArtifactsBlobsMetas(Set waasArtifactsBlobsMetas) {
        this.waasArtifactsBlobsMetas = waasArtifactsBlobsMetas;
    }
                     }
```

Exactly this method was failing

```
private ArtifactsBlobs 
        getArtifactBlobById(
            String workspaceId,
            String blobId) 
    {
public static final String GET_ARTIFACT_BLOB_BY_ID = "from ArtifactsBlobs A where A.guid = :blobId and A.workspaceId = :workspaceId";
        Map<String, Object> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
        valuesMap.put("workspaceId", workspaceId);
        valuesMap.put("blobId", blobId);
        ArtifactsBlobs artifactBlob = 
            iGenericDAO.getEntity(
                SqlQuery.GET_ARTIFACT_BLOB_BY_ID,
                valuesMap);
        
        if (artifactBlob == null) 
        {
            // Since the blobId is derived from data stored in artifacts table, 
            // absence of corr. entry in blobs table indicates data is incorrect in DB
            throw new DataIntegrityViolationException(
                "An unexpected error has occured while processing the request. Please try again later.");
        }
        
        return artifactBlob;
    }
```

And the hibernate bean configuration being

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 23 Sep, 2014 12:10:11 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.db.entity.autogen.ArtifactsBlobs" table="artifacts_blobs">
            <id name="guid" type="string">
                <column name="id" length="36" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property name="workspaceId" type="string">
                <column name="workspace_id" length="36" />
            </property>
            <property name="artifactBlobValue" type="blob">
                <column name="artifact_blob_value" not-null="true"/>
            </property>
            <property name="createdAt" type="timestamp">
                <column name="created_at" length="19" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="createdBy" type="java.lang.Long">
                <column name="created_by" />
            </property>
            <property name="updatedAt" type="timestamp">
                <column name="updated_at" length="19" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="updatedBy" type="java.lang.Long">
                <column name="updated_by" />
            </property>
            <set name="waasArtifactsBlobsMetas" table="waas_artifacts_blobs_meta" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
                <key>
                    <column name="blob_id" length="36" not-null="true" />
                </key>
                <one-to-many class="com.kony.waas.db.entity.autogen.WaasArtifactsBlobsMeta" />
            </set>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

and the Db Structure is 

    CREATE TABLE artifacts_blobs (
      id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
      workspace_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
      artifact_blob_value bytea NOT NULL,
      created_at timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      created_by bigint NOT NULL,
      updated_at timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      updated_by bigint NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ;

The saving of the POJO class is going fine but while retrieving I am facing this error
```

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.20.Final.jar:5.3.20.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1575) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.20.Final.jar:5.3.20.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1608) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.20.Final.jar:5.3.20.Final]

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \x35313162373838396435613932383937613638303266336663303236633964366332393838393638356663613039323163623538383562666164366163643039306633656335613162333734313638353539303335343662306336666164343232353362306261306
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toLong(PgResultSet.java:3253) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2436) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBlob(PgResultSet.java:456) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBlob(PgResultSet.java:442) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]

Comment: Which method in `ArtifactBlobs` class is failing? I think it's a bit hard to help if we don't know which method is being called

Comment: private ArtifactsBlobs 
  getArtifactBlobById(
   String workspaceId,
   String blobId) 
 {
  Map<String, Object> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
  valuesMap.put("workspaceId", workspaceId);
  valuesMap.put("blobId", blobId);
  ArtifactsBlobs artifactBlob = 
   iGenericDAO.getEntity(
    SqlQuery.GET_ARTIFACT_BLOB_BY_ID,
    valuesMap);
  
  if (artifactBlob == null) 
  {
   throw new DataIntegrityViolationException(
    "An unexpected error has occured while processing the request. Please try again later.");
  }
  
  return artifactBlob;
 }

Comment: And the sql query is
 public static final String GET_ARTIFACT_BLOB_BY_ID = "from ArtifactsBlobs A where A.guid = :blobId and A.workspaceId = :workspaceId";

Answer (score 0):

Your artifact blob column stores a byte array. In Postgresql, this is commonly managed using a LOB locator, which is an ID of type long. This ID is then used to retrieve the actual blob from another table. All of this is handled behind the scenes, but the retrieved data cannot be converted to a blob without a hint regarding the data type.

To map the blob property in your ArtifactBlobs class using annotations, try this:

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
private Blob artifactBlobValue;
```

For a clob, which is a blob containing only text data:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
```

I am unsure about how to translate this annotation into XML mapping. I recommend switching to Java annotation mapping, as it is a straightforward process.